# bug in "chat with an expert" prank: no "never" link or X on smaller screens

Tags: support, april-fools

The "chat with an expert" prank has an annoying bug: if your browser window isn't wide enough (I'm not sure what "enough" is), you just plain don't get the "never" link or the "X" to dismiss the dialogue.  Therefore there is no way to tell it to go away -- and given how invasive it is, that's a problem.  If you do this kind of prank (or for that matter anything serious) using this design approach, please make sure it can be dismissed in all browser configurations.

Comment: My first thought when I tried it was "this thingadongdong should be movable". Seems like that would fix this problem, too.

Comment: Isn't it already 2nd April?

Comment: @hjpotter92, it is in UTC.  It isn't where I live.  I guess they're doing the "so long as it's April 1 anywhere" timing, like they did for the date-based hats.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think it's based on the date *where you are*. I didn't *start* getting the popups until it was April 1st here in upstate New York.

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth, we consider window sizes of less then 1024 pixels to be unsupported (The "X" disappears at about 940 pixels). Why didn't you just resize your window at least for the moment?

I agree with you anyway; the placement could have been more flexible and taken these tiny windows in account somehow; I had originally considered that, but dismissed it because we had outright disabled the expert on touch devices altogether (which tend to be the only devices that have these screen real estate issues).

So for that "anything serious" that you mention, we'll continue to make the assumption of 1k pixels width, but to get rid of a joke, it'll probably be good to make that possible in any case.

Comment: Making the browser full-screen (which, in general, produces text too wide for me to read, which is why I don't do it normally) is what allowed me to diagnose the problem.  Doing that to dismiss it on every single site, main and meta, was annoying.  I understand that you design for 1024px (my entire monitor, FYI), but please consider that designs should degrade gracefully beyond designed-for parameters.  Making it movable (suggested in a comment above) would have fixed this.  Putting the "never" link on the left would have fixed it.  Making the box smaller might have fixed it.

Comment: (Also, on my tablet I usually use the full site, not mobile, and prefer portrait orientation for reading, so while I wasn't using my tablet last night, that would have failed too.  The mobile design is great for my phone, but a tablet can do better.)  Thanks for the future consideration.

Comment: @Monica The SE design uses a fixed width for the content area. It doesn't matter how big you make the window, that ensures the text won't ever get too wide to read. Do you mean you have to keep the window smaller because other sites you browse aren't so well designed? There's a simple solution for that... :-)

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, shockingly, Stack Exchange isn't my only destination on the internet.  In addition, I have to zoom fonts (or override CSS with Stylish) to make some sites usable for me at all -- SE included, by the way -- so when all is said and done, I'm probably not having the user experience that SE's designers intended -- but if I did I wouldn't be able to read the text with my vision.  My point is that we should try to make sites work for users who aren't using the same environment as the devs, too, in the interests of having a wider audience.